# How to find the Addition of a Housenumber (in an address) by using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need the addition of a housenumber in an address. How do you do that?

This is my code.

```
    string result = string.Empty;
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<houseNumber>[\d]+\-*[\d]+)(-*)(\s?)(?<addition>[0-9a-zA-Z]{1})");
    Match match = rgx.Match(fullHouseNumber);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        result = match.Groups["addition"].Value;
    }
    return result;
```

By example:

1. **50 ABC** the result has to be **"ABC"**. Now I only get the **"A"** <=> Wrong answer!
2. **50 A** the result has to be **"A"**. Now I only get the **"A"** <=> OK
3. **50 50** the result has to be **"50"**. Now I get the **"5"** <=> Wrong
4. **50** the result has to be **""**. Now I only get the **""** <=> OK
5. **50-10** the result has to be **"10"**. Now I only get the **"0"** <=> Wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select only 1 character:

```
(?<houseNumber>[\d]+\-*[\d]+)(-*)(\s?)(?<addition>[0-9a-zA-Z]{1})
                                                              ^
```

change this to:

```
(?<houseNumber>[\d]+\-*[\d]+)(-*)(\s?)(?<addition>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)
```

**Update**

check this one:

```
(?<houseNumber>[\d]+[\s\-](?<addition>[0-9a-zA-Z]+))
```

Comment: Thanks. Only result number 5 is still wrong.

Comment: let me check that

Comment: @user1531040 please check my updated answer

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani i'm testing it in [RegExr](http://regexr.com/5i7b5) but seems the `50-10` isn't right

Comment: @StefanoCavion it is right, the reason you are getting this result, because you are checking global and it finds 50 from the row before and then \s and then gets the 50 in the next row as result, but as each of these are going to be checked separately this can't happen. remove all other lines (except 50-10) and you will get what I mean